# Copy a range of cells with exclusion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below and hope that you could possibly help

The code currently is basically to copy a range of cells in a active worksheet or all other work sheets set up the same way. As soon as the code identifies a "NO" which is in cell range S26:S69, it will copy the cell values on a command button click.

This code works 100% all good however. I was just wondering although I tell the code to copy when detecting NO in range S, I would at the same time like to override the NO identification. So if the code sees NO it will copy but because it then sees "Repeat Finding" (which will be in row range R26:R69)it will not copy NO instruction as range R overrides that request irrespective whether NO is selected or not.

I hope that all makes sense

```
Sub Submit_AuditSheet_Data()

    Dim cell As Range

    Set ws_from = ActiveSheet
    Set ws_to = Sheets("Findings_Summary_Sheet")
    lrow = ws_to.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' finds that last used row in column "A"

    For Each cell In ws_from.Range("S26:S69")

        If cell.Value = "No" Then

            lrow = lrow + 1
            ws_to.Range("A" & lrow).Value = ws_from.Range("B" & cell.Row).Value
            ws_to.Range("B" & lrow).Resize(1, 14).Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns("O:AB").Value

        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Change 'If cell.Value = "No" Then'  to  'If cell.Value = "No" And cell.Offset(, -1).Value <> "Repeat Finding" Then'.

Comment: I get a error message

Comment: Error read "Expected ; Then or GoTo

Comment: Ok, found the problem thank you

Comment: My answer in the comments was wrong. The wrong data was being copied. See the solution in my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy With Two Criteria

**The Code**

```
' Use 'Option Explicit' because it will force you to qualify all variables
' and help you to find errors much faster.
Option Explicit

Sub Submit_AuditSheet_Data()

    ' It is good practice to describe or name the variables.
    ' It is good practice to 'throw in' a CAPITALIZED letter in the variables,
    ' which will make finding typos quicker. This is usually preferred
    ' to using underscores (_).
    Dim ws_From As Worksheet   ' Source Sheet
    Dim ws_To As Worksheet     ' Target Sheet
    ' 'cell' is fine, because 'Cell' is more difficult to identify if there
    ' are instances of the 'Range.Cells' property in the code.
    Dim cell As Range          ' Current Criteria Cell Range
    Dim lRow As Long           ' Last Non-Empty Row (in Column 'A'
                               ' of Target Sheet (ws_To))
    Dim NoRec As Long          ' Number of Records Copied

    ' Using ActiveSheet is usually bad practice.
    ' For example, select the sheet "Findings_Summary_Sheet" and go to VBE.
    ' Now run the code. In this case it probably will find nothing to copy
    ' because the ActiveSheet is the wrong sheet ("Findings_Summary_Sheet").
    ' In a worse case scenario it could overwrite same valuable data.
    ' On the other hand, if the code is in a module and you're going to put
    ' a commandbutton (that will run this code) on several sheets
    ' then it's even a must, because the ActiveSheet will be the one
    ' containing the command button.
    ' Developer > Controls > Insert > ActiveX Controls > Command Button...
    ' CommandButton1 code:
    'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '    Submit_AuditSheet_Data
    'End Sub
    Set ws_From = ActiveSheet
    ' It is fine to use spaces in sheet (tab) names.
    Set ws_To = Sheets("Findings_Summary_Sheet")
    ' Although it's not necessary in this case, it is good practice to use
    ' 'ws_To.Rows.Count' instead of 'Rows.Count'.
    ' Consider learning how to calculate the last non-empty row using
    ' the Find method since the 'xlUp' method might give you the wrong
    ' result if you have filtered data or hidden rows in the sheet.
    lRow = ws_To.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NoRec = lRow

' While developing the code, use 'Debug.Print' to monitor (current) results
' of variables. When done, delete or better outcomment the 'Debug.Print' lines,
' because they will slow down your code (Think thousands of lines).

' See the results of Debug.Print in the Immediate window (GTRL+G).
Debug.Print String(40, "-")
Debug.Print "ws_From      = " & ws_From.Name
Debug.Print "ws_To        = " & ws_To.Name
Debug.Print "lRow (ws_To) = " & lRow & " (" & ws_To.Name & ")"
Debug.Print String(40, "-")

    For Each cell In ws_From.Range("S26:S69")
        ' Write down the logic your are trying to apply:
        ' Copy ranges if 'R' <> "Repeat Finding, but only if 'S' = "No" or
        ' Copy ranges if 'S' = "No", but only if 'R' <> "Repeat Finding".
        If cell.Offset(, -1) <> "Repeat Finding" Then
            ' Now when you think about it, you can actually switch
            ' the previous and the next line.
            If cell.Value = "No" Then

                lRow = lRow + 1
                ws_To.Range("A" & lRow).Value = _
                  ws_From.Range("B" & cell.Row).Value
                ws_To.Range("B" & lRow).Resize(1, 14).Value = _
                  cell.EntireRow.Columns("O:AB").Value

' See the results of Debug.Print in the Immediate window (GTRL+G).
Debug.Print cell.Address(False, False), _
  cell.Offset(, -1).Address(False, False), _
  ws_To.Range("A" & lRow).Address(False, False), _
  ws_From.Range("B" & cell.Row).Address(False, False), _
  ws_To.Range("B" & lRow).Resize(1, 14).Address(False, False), _
  cell.EntireRow.Columns("O:AB").Address(False, False)

            End If

        End If

    Next cell

' See the results of Debug.Print in the Immediate window (GTRL+G).
Debug.Print String(40, "-")
Debug.Print "lRow (ws_To) = " & lRow & " (" & ws_To.Name & ")"
Debug.Print String(40, "-")

    ' It is good practice to end such a code with a message, because
    ' sometimes it is hard to tell if the code has already run.
    Dim strMsg As String
    NoRec = lRow - NoRec

' See the results of Debug.Print in the Immediate window (GTRL+G).
Debug.Print "NoRec        = " & NoRec
Debug.Print String(40, "-")

    If NoRec <> 1 Then strMsg = "s"
    MsgBox "Copied " & NoRec & " record" & strMsg & ".", _
      vbInformation, "Audit Sheet Data Submitted"

End Sub
```

**A Sample Result From the Immediate Window**

```
----------------------------------------
ws_From      = Sheet1
ws_To        = Findings_Summary_Sheet
lRow (ws_To) = 1 (Findings_Summary_Sheet)
----------------------------------------
S35           R35           A2            B35           B2:O2         O35:AB35
S37           R37           A3            B37           B3:O3         O37:AB37
S39           R39           A4            B39           B4:O4         O39:AB39
S41           R41           A5            B41           B5:O5         O41:AB41
S45           R45           A6            B45           B6:O6         O45:AB45
S49           R49           A7            B49           B7:O7         O49:AB49
S50           R50           A8            B50           B8:O8         O50:AB50
S53           R53           A9            B53           B9:O9         O53:AB53
S55           R55           A10           B55           B10:O10       O55:AB55
S58           R58           A11           B58           B11:O11       O58:AB58
S64           R64           A12           B64           B12:O12       O64:AB64
S65           R65           A13           B65           B13:O13       O65:AB65
S67           R67           A14           B67           B14:O14       O67:AB67
----------------------------------------
lRow (ws_To) = 14 (Findings_Summary_Sheet)
----------------------------------------
NoRec        = 13
----------------------------------------
```

**A Message Box Sample**

[image]